# Фон строк в PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

[image: Скриншот]

В общем и целом все видно на скриншоте. Вопрос скорее глупый, но меня это ужасно раздражает и самостоятельно вернуть "все как было" я не смог, даже настройки по умолчанию не помогают :( Черный фон только в пределах head, кстати.

Comment: Ищите в настройках... в районе Color&Fonts -> General/HTML ......там много всяких таких настроек...но все упирается Color&Fonts

Comment: Да, действительно в Color&Fonts->General был Injected Language Fragment. Странно, но до Вашего ответа я перепробовал все возможные комбинации в том же Color&Fonts. Спасибо)